# Many great solutions for one problem – who wins?

Tags: discussion, accepting

Recently I asked the question
[\footnotetext numbering for many \footnotemark - automatic solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43692/footnotetext-numbering-for-many-footnotemark-automatic-solution)
and I received three nice solutions.
Each has its advantages.

Which answer should be accepted?

- Person who addressed my question precisely?
- Person how provides more comfortable solution than what I asked for?
- Is it still my choice or should I toss a coin?

Comment: Whilst not completely relevant, the answers at this question: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/562/86 might help.  In particular, Will's comment to "not worry too much".

Answer (score 14):

To reward both answers you could

- up-vote both,
- accept the answer that address your question precisely, and
- award a 50 points bounty to the other solution.

When you choose award a bounty you can choose as motivation "Reward existing answer", then you wait until you can reward the bounty and you give it to the answer you want to reward.

Comment: I can't find "bounty" button :/. Any clue?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki Your question is too recent to be able to put bounties on. Questions are eligible for bounties when they are 2 days old, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty for details.

Comment: Thank you, I've forgot that I've put it so recently. Thanks for support :).